# Determining primality [Turing]

Tags: primes, turing-lang

```
put "enter a number to determine if it is or is not prime"
get primenum
% for i : 1 .. primenum by 1
% end for
if (primenum / primenum) = 1 or primenum / 1 = 0 then
    put primenum, " is a prime number"
else
    put primenum, " is not a prime number"
end if
```

Output says that 12 is a prime number, we know that's wrong so...
What's wrong with my code, and how might I fix it?

Comment: Even numbers above two don't need to be tested at all, right?

Comment: wrong, any given number needs to be tested.

Comment: There are no even prime numbers above two.

Comment: I think you will find that there are no even prime numbers greater than 2.

Comment: I believe (n mod n) = 0 for all n, prime or not.

Comment: That was the point, hence they don't need to be tested for prime-ness. You will still need to test for even-ness.

Comment: @Closers: "Not a real question." Really? They asked a clear question in their title "How do I determine if a number is a prime number?", provided some code and input on which they know they are getting an incorrect result and asked a clear "how can i solve this problem?" which can be interpreted as "what is wrong with my code and how would I fix it?"

Comment: @Jason: When you have to do your own interpretation like that, you can no longer describe it as clear. It was vague and poorly asked---as are many questions that throw up code and say, in essence, "plz help". (starbuck: it helps to describe what you've tried and what specific part is confusing you.)  However, it is a duplicate anyway, because I know we've never had primality test questions before.

Comment: @Roger Pate: You make a valid point.

Comment: And it looks like I vandalized it when removing [turing].  starbuck: Is that the language in which this is written? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_(programming_language%29  Please edit the question to ask about Turing's syntax if that's what is causing your confusion.

Comment: Yes, it was a Turing question for a class I took years ago. I've long since lost interest in learning Turing, however I'll leave this so other might find it and learn something If the question can be improved I welcome anyone to edit it.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I don't know that language, but it looks to be fairly easy to read. Your first problem is this line:

```
if (primenum / primenum) = 1 or primenum / 1 = 0 then
```

This is testing to see if `primenum` divided by `primenum` is one or if `primenum` divided by one is zero. The first condition will always be true and thus your algorithm will report that every integer is a prime number.

Let's recall the definition of a prime number. A natural number `n` is prime if it has exactly two distinct natural number divisors. This means that to check and see if `n` is prime you must validate that there are no other divisors of `n` except for `1` and `n` itself (note that implicitly `n` can not be equal to `1` otherwise its only divisors are `1` and `1` which are not distinct). To do this, just consider all possible numbers that could be divisors of `n` excluding `1` and `n` itself and check if any of them divide `n`. This means that we just loop from `2` to `n - 1` checking if any of these numbers evenly divide `n`. The natural numbers in the range `2` to `n - 1` are the only possible numbers that could invalidate `n` from being prime.

Thus, the most naive way to implement a test as to whether a number is prime is following. Accept as input a number `n`. Then, check to see if `n` is less than `2`. If it is it can not be a prime number. Then, loop from `2` to `n - 1`; call the loop variable `k`. Check to see if any `k` in `2` to `n - 1` evenly divides `n` (`if n mod k = 0`). If there is such a `k`, then `n` can not be prime and you can break from the loop. Otherwise, if the loop terminates without breaking then `n` is prime. So, in pseudocode

```
integer n
get n
boolean flag
if n < 2
    flag = false
else
    flag = true
    for k = 2 to n - 1
        if n mod k = 0 
            flag = false
            break
if flag
    print "prime"
else
    print "not prime"
```

Now, just one minor comment about your code. Don't name the input `primenum`. A reader of your code might that think that `primenum` is in fact a prime number because you named it so. A name like `valueToTest` would be strongly preferred here.

Comment: You can even limit the loop to values between 2 and sqrt(n) instead of n-1.

Comment: The other "trivial" optimization is to check 2, and then only check odd numbers.

Comment: @gregseth, @Anon.: I said "thus, the most naive way to implement a test as to whether a number is prime is following." There is absolutely no need to optimize this to someone that is clearly trying to learn. He can get fancy later.

Comment: The first thing you should do after learning the naive approach is to try and improve it to make sure you actually understand it.

Comment: @Anon.: That statement I agree with.

Comment: Not to mention that the "even number" optimization is kind of silly... if you're going to pre-screen by checking that the number is divisible by 2, why not also screen out numbers divisible by 3, and 5, and 7, and... you get the idea.  Beginner question - keep it simple.

Comment: It is not at all silly. It cuts the evaluation time in half without complicating the loop at all - you just have `k+=2` instead of `k++`. If you instead try to screen out any other number, the loop becomes much more complex.

Comment: It's Turing. Someone edited the question and removed the `Turing` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code ... doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
% for i : 1 .. primenum by 1
% end for
```

Wooh. Empty loop. Doesn't do anything except burn clock cycles.

```
if (primenum mod primenum) = 0
```

Will always be `true`.

Also, you've got your condition the wrong way around. If it *is* divisible by something (other than itself and 1), then it is *not* prime.

The solution? Probably rewrite it in psuedocode and then turn that into real code, rather than trying to hack up something without understanding it at all.

Comment: you're right, although you maybe didn't notice i had commented that loop out. although i supposed i can just delete it, i don't really need a loop here do i?

Comment: Yes, you will still need a loop. No, `if (primenum / primenum) = 1` is *still* always going to be true.

Comment: Don't be so ruthless with beginners, +1 to calm you

Comment: I don't need the +1. What I need is sleep, which I'm not getting enough of these days.

Answer (score 0):

The defining property of a prime is not that it *is* divisible by 1 and itself (all number have those properties), but that it *is not* divisible by anything else.

Try working from there.